# How to write a class to restrict object creation to once in case of multilevel inheritance?

Tags: java

Suppose we have three classes A,B and C

```
class A{
    
    A(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    
}

class B extends A{
    
    B(){
        //super
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

class C extends B{
    
    C(){
        //super
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}

public class Main{
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        C c = new C(); // This will print ABC and that is fine

        C c' = new C(); // Should not be allowed
    }
}
```

I want to put some logic so that C c' = new C() should not be allowed after creation of c. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. I was asked this question in interview and interviewer threw a hint saying " You can do something with super ". But I failed to answer.

Comment: What if I create `A a = new A()`? What should happen at calling `B b = new B();` after it?

Comment: What does `super` have to do with this? Could you elaborate on the requirements?

Comment: @hev1 I think the OP meant `super()` when they put `//super`

Comment: @OP did you mean `print` instead of `println`? `println` wouldn't print `ABC`, since they'd all be on separate lines. Also, by `//super`, did you mean `super();`?

Comment: Do you want to make C, B and A as singleton class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the singleton pattern.

```
class C extends B {
  
  private static class SingletonHolder {
    static final C SINGLETON = new C();
  }
  
  private C() {
    super();
    System.out.print("C");
  }

  public static C getInstance() {
    return SingletonHolder.SINGLETON;
  }
}
```

This way, it will only print `ABC` once, the first time `getInstance` is called, because `SingletonHolder` will only be loaded when you call `getInstance`.

You can then use it like this:

```
C c = C.getInstance();
```

If you instead want a runtime exception, then you can keep a static boolean field in `C` telling if `C`'s constructor has already been called, and throw an exception if someone tries to instantiate it again. However, I doubt that's what the interviewer was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Not sure why he mentioned super (this confused me during interview). But I think this will definitely solve the problem.